# Sequelize INSERT handling Object that has sometimes value of NULL as an attribute

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to insert multiple objects to a Postgres database using Sequelize ORM. These objects are obtained from another project that I personally can't change or modify. These objects will have attributes that have object inside them.
Example object:

```
{
id:1,
name:'foo',
created:{user:{'insertattributehere'},date:'insertdatehere'},
modify:{user:{'insertattributehere'},date:'insertdatehere'},
}
```

For simplicity purposes, I have created a table that has each attribute of object as a column which will have a datatype of String(id as string, name as string, created_user_attribute, created_date etc).
So when inserting the object, I would simply the following INSERT.

```
const new_user = await ClassName.create({id: object.id, name: object.name, created_user_attribute: object.user.attribute ...})
```

However, sometimes, the attribute that contains another object can be null, for example

```
{
id:2,
name:'bar',
created:{date:'insertdatehere'}, notice that created doesnt have attribute User
modify:{user:{'insertattributehere'},date:'insertdatehere'},
}
```

This will result on TypeError, since 'created' doesn't have 'user' attribute. What I want is a method to somehow will handle this TypeError, and insert a NULL value (or "" for the string)

I could, as a last resort, manually check every attribute for a null value to handle the TypeError, and then create a nested statement such that I will insert a no value string instead. However, this looks very repetitive and inelegant.

Is there a way to handle this problem in a better way? Note that I can't change the objects that I want to insert to my database.

Comment: You can use the spread operator along with the optional chaining operator to get only defined props and if omitted proos has no default value in DB they will have null values by default

Comment: @Anatoly, sorry could you elaborate more on "Spread + Optional chaining operator"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lodash` function `omitBy` along with the optional chaining operator to get only defined props and if omitted props has no default value in DB they will have null values by default:

```js
const new_user = await ClassName.create(
  _.omitBy({
    id: object.id,
    name: object.name,
    created_user_attribute: object.user?.attribute
  }, _.isUndefined)
)
```